Why is this way of calculating probability of getting a combination wrong?
Suppose we have a set with $m$ elements, we know that the combination of $k$ elements is $m \choose k$. I want to know the probability of getting one specific combination. My question is which way is the correct and why does this happen:
$$\frac{1}{m \choose k} \ne \prod^k_{i = 0}{\frac{1}{m - k}}$$
For the LHS we know we want $1$ combination out of the total number of combinations, so applying simple probability calculations we can get it. For the RHS we use the reasoning that first we first pick one element from the total, then other one from the total minus one, then another one from the total minus 2, etc. Both reasonings seem correct to me, since the other one will give you also a combination, however they do not give the same answer.
As an example, if we set $m=40$ and $k=3$ then we get that for the LHS $\frac{1}{40 \choose 3} = \frac{1}{9880} \approx 0.0001$; however, for the RHS, we get $\frac{1}{40} \cdot \frac{1}{37} \cdot \frac{1}{38} = 1/59\,280 \approx 0.00002$, an order of $10$ smaller.
What is the correct answer? What is the explanation for the different results?

For the product you are requiring a specific combination in a specific order.

@lulu Okay, so if I want to the specific combination I should use the LHS formula, since I don't care about order, isn't it? Thank you.

Since there are $k!$ possible orders, that's the ratio between the two sides.

To pick 1 combination out of the total number of combinations, the first pick has $k/m$ probability to be OK, then the second pick has $(k-1)/(m-1) probability to be OK, etc.

A mildly droll, possible source of confusion: locker combinations are not combinations in this sense, they're permutations (i.e., order matters).
